# Can you use older version of MySQL with Heroku?

Tags: mysql, heroku

Is it possible to use an older version of MySQL with Heroku?

Specifically Server Version: 5.0.88-community-nt

Thanks!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you may have to install a mysql2psql reference migrated data, so I believe, no (on the older version). Heroku deems it best to use their Postgre. The only thing I could think of is a Heroku add-on with MySQL.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Looking back this was a pretty bad question.

Heroku has many service providers that you can ask to setup whatever MySQL environment you need.   Check the app add-ons or setup your own and connect out by setting your own MySQL environment variables.